# How to store my username and password securely to mysql DB using c# asp.net

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a login form and will have two textboxes such as username and password.How can i store the datas from these textboxes to DB using asp.net.Please provide anyone me the codes...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database

Comment: Do you  want any encryption code or you want the way how to store values in DB?

Comment: check this link for Rijindeal encryption - http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/704372/How-to-use-Rijndael-ManagedEncryption-with-Csharp